# Google Sheets Apps Script Matching Source Destination Sheets having same name tabs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've a need to copy values between tabs of source & destination sheets. The tabs are same name H1, H2, H3 in both sheets. Copying is between tabs of same name i.e., H1->H1, H2->H2, etc. The script is attached below. Every time I've to run the script, I'm changing the sheet name manually. How to do it in one go?

```
    function updateSourceToTarget(sourceID,sourceName,targetID,targetname){
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source").getSheetByName("H1");
var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Dest").getSheetByName("H1");
var sourcelastRow = source.getLastRow();
var sourcelastCol = source.getLastColumn();
var sourcedata = source.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).getValues();
destination.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).setValues(sourcedata);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Iterate over an array of the sheet names `["H1","H2","H3"]` with a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop.

- Put all the sheet names in that array, and the script will take care of the task for every set of source and destination sheet.

### Solution:

```
function updateSourceToTarget(sourceID,sourceName,targetID,targetname){         
    const sheetNames = ["H1","H2","H3"];
    sheetNames.forEach(h=>{                             
          let source = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Source").getSheetByName(h);
          let destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Dest").getSheetByName(h);
          let sourcelastRow = source.getLastRow();
          let sourcelastCol = source.getLastColumn();
          let sourcedata = source.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).getValues();
          destination.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).setValues(sourcedata);                                                                                                                                         
    });    
}
```

and I guess this is the final version that uses the function parameters:

```
function updateSourceToTarget(sourceID,targetID){ 
    const sheetNames = ["H1","H2","H3"];  
    sheetNames.forEach(h=>{                             
           let source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID).getSheetByName(h);
           let destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetID).getSheetByName(h);
           let sourcelastRow = source.getLastRow();
           let sourcelastCol = source.getLastColumn();
           let sourcedata = source.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).getValues();
           destination.getRange(1,1,sourcelastRow,sourcelastCol).setValues(sourcedata);                                                                                                                                         
    });  
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted... Thank you